# From xml in SQL Server, get next sibling value

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I've got a table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE CustomerXmlData
(CustomerId int,
CustomerData xml)
```

The CustomerId links to the main customer table and the CustomerData is an xml document that looks like this

```
<Person>
  <Product>
    <Name>ABC</Name>
    <Value>500</Value>
  </Product>
  <Product>
    <Name>XYZ</Name>
    <Value>600</Value>
  </Product>
</Person>
```

There are several hundred thousand such rows. In pseudocode, what I want to do is "Find the average `Value` of `Product` where `Name` = 'XYZ'".

I know how to get values out based on element attributes or based on having a parent that is unique in the document, but neither of those is any use in this situation. I can't find anything that will let me locate the `Name` that I want and then get the value of the next sibling.

I can use `FOR XML` and create an edge table, but would I then have to loop through that with a cursor? I'm hoping for a more efficient solution.

Comment: if it's SQL Server 2005 it has XQuery support (thou on its XML tables), if you know a bit of XPath maybe can be a good starting point. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345122%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

Comment: I knew a bit of XPath....now I know a bit more. Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (edited to filter by Name):

```
DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(50)
SET @Name = 'XYZ'

SELECT Name, AVG(Value) 
FROM (
SELECT 
    c.value('Name[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS Name
    , c.value('Value[1]', 'DECIMAL') AS Value
FROM CustomerXmlData
CROSS APPLY CustomerData.nodes('//Product[Name = sql:variable("@Name")]') AS t(c)
) T
GROUP BY Name
```

Answer (score 7):

> I can't find anything that will let me locate the Name that I want and
>   then get the value of the next sibling.

```
declare @Name varchar(10)
set @Name = 'XYZ'

select N.value('.', 'int') as Value    
from CustomerXmlData
  cross apply CustomerData.nodes
    ('/Person/Product[Name = sql:variable("@Name")]/Value') as T(N)
```

Comment: Upvoting for the right answer. I missed the "WHERE Name = 'XYZ'" bit. Edited my answer.